# How to backup files via SFTP to a network drive?

Tags: backup

I have a Windows laptop. Every night, I backup my files on my laptop to an external harddrive that is connected via USB to my router and mapped to my computer as a network drive. This allows me to have automated backups to a physical harddrive (when I'm at home) without plugging anything in to my laptop itself.

Now, I am also a researcher who accesses a cluster at my lab every day. I SSH in to do my work and use SFTP to transfer files from my account on the cluster to my local machine, as needed (I have a username and password). I would like to automatically backup the files on my account on the cluster to my harddrive at home every night as well.

What are some ways I can do this? I can't add the cluster account as a network location on my Windows machine and sync from there since Windows only allows FTP, not SFTP.

Comment: Can you provide more details like which SFTP/SSH utility you use? SSH, SFTP and SCP are all options that support key-pair authentication. This allows password-less login to the server which is perfect for backups. However, this feature/authentication should be enabled on your server

Comment: Certainly. I use cmder (which is really just ConEmu) as my terminal to SSH into the cluster. I use WinSCP to do file transfers. To backup my local files on my machine to the harddrive, I've been using Cobian Backup (since that allows for automated and timed backups, is free, and can backup to a network drive), but I don't really care what backup software I use as long as it works. Cobian Backup doesn't have an option to backup files via SFTP though - just local files.

Comment: Hey, given the amount of data you need to back up you can use https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule along with https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key. Note that this will not be as efficient as incremental backup or `rsync`... Btw: [this](https://www.duplicati.com) seems to worth a look

Comment: WinSCP file transfers take so long for me. I'm not really sure why. So that's definitely an option, but one I don't know if I want to pursue (I did enable the password-less login, so that's fantastic!). The link you posted to Duplicati was useful. Duplicati itself doesn't seem like a suitable option for me because it can only back up files that are stored on the machine where Duplicati is installed (and I can't install software on the research cluster). That being said, sifting through alternatives led me to a number of options. [Syncovery](https://www.syncovery.com/) is what I'm testing out.